# If $A \subseteq B$ then is $diam(A)\leq diam(B)$

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $A$ and $B$ be subset of $X$ and $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Prove that If $A \subseteq B$ then is $diam(A)\leq diam(B)$.

 My work

$$B = A \cup (B\setminus A)$$
$$diam(B) = d(A \cup (B\setminus A)) \leq diam(A) + diam(B \setminus A) + d(A,B\setminus A) $$
$$diam(B)\leq diam(A) + diam(B \setminus A) + d(A,B\setminus A) $$
But I don't know how to finish.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you finish that thing specifically, but I do know how I start and finish: $A\subseteq B$ implies $A\times A\subseteq B\times B$ and therefore $$\sup\{d(x,y)\,:\, (x,y)\in A\times A\}\le\sup\{d(x,y)\,:\, (x,y)\in B\times B\}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\{d(a_1,a_2): a_1,a_2 \in A\} \subseteq \{d(b_1,b_2): b_1,b_2 \in A\}$. If $E$ and $F$ are sets of real numbers and $E $ is contained in $F$ the $\sup E \leq \sup F$.